# Is data binding in javafx only possible during variable declaration?

Tags: data-binding, javafx

Looking at the javafx tutorials and samples, bindings are always made during varibale declarations:

```
def y = bind x;
```

or

```
def address = Address {
  street: bind myStreet;
};
```

But what do I do, if I have an exisiting object - and hence don't declare it - and want to bind one of its attributes. In my case I load a SVGPath with the FXDLoader and then want to bind SVGPath.visible to a variable. How can I achieve this?

```
var data = true;
var fxdContent = FXDLoader.load("{__DIR__}plan.fxz");
var sc = fxdContent.lookup("SC0013") as SVGPath;
sc.visible = bind data; //That doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a replace trigger instead e.g.

```
var fxdContent = FXDLoader.load("{__DIR__}plan.fxz");
var sc = fxdContent.lookup("SC0013") as SVGPath;
var data = true on replace {
    sc.visible = data;
}
```

You might also be able to do:

```
def data = bind sc.visible with inverse;
```

This would give you bidirectional updates between the two variables. According to the [language specification](http://openjfx.java.sun.com/current-build/doc/reference/Binding.html), you can't use "bind" anywhere else.

Comment: thanks! that works! But nevertheless I'm interessed in the bind question.

Comment: I updated the answer to include another possible solution and a link to the relevant section in the language specification.

Comment: thanks for the second solution. didn't know that one. and I didn't knew the language spec either, only the stuff at javafx.com ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can bind a variable only when you are declaring it.